# How can I understand if my MX is changing the message envelope?

Tags: email, exim, gmail, email-bounces, smtp-headers

I have an exim4 server that forwards all input emails to a gmail account.

Gmail is refusing some valid messages with this error:

> SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 550-5.7.1
> Our system has detected that this message
> is likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam
> sent to Gmail,this message has been blocked. Please
> visit https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedMessageError
> for more information.

I guess one of the problem is that my server is forwarding all messages, spam too. I have read this articlet from google support:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/175365?hl=en

Seems that I have to be sure to not change the envelope, but how can I understand if my exim4 server is changing it?

Comment: Well, what do the headers of messages that Gmail choses to accept say?

Comment: There are a planty of headers, what is the relevant ones? I could not understand which ones should be not touched during forward to not invalidate DKIM signature, and which ones has to be rewritten by SRS.
By one hand seems not possibile to rewrite due to DKIM signature, by other hand if I don't rewrite sender the SPF is not accepted.